# Information on people arriving from America

Tags: usa, uk, visas-on-arrival

When someone arrives in the UK from America they join a queue to get their passport stamped and they might get a few questions.  What information do they already know about the person if it's their first time?  I read here that the airline gives some information but it does not say exactly what it is. Where can I see the things they already know?  Do they already know something that can cause the person to be denied?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  You might want to ask the question about your concern rather than about the information that a UK government might have about a person arriving at the border.

Comment: They have a clean history

Comment: So what's the concern?

Comment: What they already know

Comment: And why would it matter what they already know?  What is the actual concern?  There is information sharing between US and UK so they may know a lot or they may know nothing but a name.  What is the actual concern?  That someone may get refused entry?  The border control agent may do that anyway knowing absolutely nothing about you except your name and passport number.

Comment: Do they have the person's credit card details?

Comment: If there is a reason to have it they might.

Comment: Yes, the carrier is legally required to provide the credit card details if it was used for either reservation or payment.  They also have to provide a list of any other passengers whose reservation or payment was made on the same card.

Comment: @GayotFow wow, thanks for that.  It never occurred to me to suspect such a thing.

Comment: @phoog, it's very helpful for them to be able to plug in a credit card number and see what's going on from that perspective.  It's a great way for them to catch people out.  Also when billing addresses match up, etc etc...